# Channel Forms - How to set Custom Form attributes

Tags: channel-form

How do I set custom form attributes for `{exp:channel:form}` tag?

I want to set this attribute `role="form"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin does that, but I don't think it supports the role param. It would be real easy to add though.

https://github.com/jazonv/SafeCracker-HTML5-Attributes

Comment: I will just fork it to add my own attributes. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Channel Forms unfortunately - the channel forms library doesn't contain the EE global (as the Safecracker library did), so it fails.

Comment: That's not likely the cause. The EE global is still used, but it's not assigned to the $this->EE property. I haven't tested it to what is wrong, but it could easily be fixed.

Comment: Yes, on doing some more investigation that's not the cause. However, just changing the hook to 'channel_form_entry_form_tagdata_end' doesn't work. This line generates the error: $params = $this->obj->EE->TMPL->tagparams;  - I assumed that the problem was referencing EE as part of the CF object, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Channel Forms (EE 2.7+), than this should work for you: https://github.com/tobystokes/EE-SafeCracker-HTML5-Attributes